# Trying to take a variable out of a function to be used in another function

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am creating a database in sqlite3, with python 3.7, and I am trying to take the variable "username out a function" and use it in the post() function (line 104), such that I can tie the user account to the "posts" table, so they post can be read by the user. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
import sqlite3, datetime

conn = sqlite3.connect("Database.db")

conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users
  (username PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  email TEXT NOT NULL,
  time DATETIME NOT NULL,
  password INT NOT NULL); ''')

conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts
    (username PRIMARY KEY,
    yourpost TEXT NOT NULL,
    current DATETIME NOT NULL);''')

now = datetime.datetime.now()
current = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
#print(current)

def signUp():
    while True:
        username = input("Please create a username:")
        if 0 < len(username) < 16:
            check = conn.execute("SELECT name FROM Users WHERE username = ?",(username,)).fetchone()
            if check == None:
                break
            else:
                print("This username is taken. Please use another one\n")
    while True:
        name = input("Please enter your full name:")
        if 0 < len(name) < 30 and ' ' in name:
            break                   
    while True:
        email = input("Please enter your email address:")
        if '@' in email:
            break
    while True:
        password = input("Please enter a 6 character password:")
        if len(password) == 6:
          break 
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO Users(username,name,email,time,password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)" , (username, name, email, current, password))
    conn.commit()

    print("Your details have been successfully saved\n")

    details = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ?', (username,)).fetchall() 
    print("Your information: ", details)

def signIn():
    while True:
        usernameInput = input("Please enter your username:")
        check = conn.execute("SELECT name FROM Users WHERE username = ?",(usernameInput,)).fetchone()
        if check != None:
            break
        else:
            print('There were no users found under that name')
    while True:
        passwordInput = input("Please enter your password:")
        check = conn.execute("SELECT name FROM Users WHERE password = ? AND username = ?",(passwordInput, usernameInput)).fetchone()
        if check != None:
            break
        else:
            print("Your password is incorrect. Please try again")

    details = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ?",(usernameInput,)).fetchone()
    print("Your information: ", details)
    return usernameInput


def menuOption():
    print("Do you want to:\n1)Sign up\n2)Sign in")
    while True:
        userResponse = input(">>> ")
        if userResponse == "1" or userResponse == "2":
            break
        else:
            print("You must choose option 1 or option 2")
    if(userResponse == "1"):
        signUp()
    elif(userResponse == "2"):
        signIn()

def get_all():
    print('\nDisplaying all user info :\n')
    allusers = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM Users').fetchall()
    for i in allusers:
        print(i)

def show_posts():
    print ("Posts:\n")
    allposts = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM posts").fetchall()
    for i in allposts:
        print(i)

def show_Yourposts():
    print("Your posts:\n")
    ypost = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username =?", (username,)).fetchall()
    for i in ypost:
        print(i)



def post():
    yourpost = input("This is your new post, type whatever you want")
    while True:
        if len(yourpost) < 300:
            print(yourpost)
            conn.execute("INSERT INTO posts(username,yourpost,current) VALUES(?,?,?)", (username,yourpost, current))
            conn.commit()
            break
        elif len(yourpost) > 300:
            print ("Post is longer than 300 characters. Unable to post.")
            break




def wpost():
    print("Do you want to: \n(Y)create a post\n(N)not")
    while True:
      userResponse2 = input(">>> ")
      if userResponse2 == "Y" or userResponse2 == 'N':
        break
      else:
          print("You must choose option Y OR option N")
    if(userResponse2 == "Y"):
        post()
    if (userResponse2 == "N"):
        print("Do you want to: \n(Y) view your post\n (N) not")
        while True:
            userResponse3 = input(">>> ")
            if userResponse3 == "Y" or userResponse3 == "N":
                break
            else:
                print("You must choose option Y OR option N")
        if (userResponse3 == "Y"):
            show_Yourposts()
        if userResponse3 == "N":
            print("Showing all user data:\n")
            get_all()







menuOption()

wpost()

conn.close()
```

Comment: just to be clear, you're trying to take the ```username``` from the ```signUp``` function?

Comment: S. L. Yeah that's the one

Comment: I mean I am actually surprised some of the code works right now, for instance ```show_Yourposts``` uses ```username``` which is uninitiated in both the global and function context... Have you considered passing ```username``` as a variable for those functions that need it?

Comment: I have tried that, but then I get an error "username is not defined" Also, I am trying to make username work in the show_Yourposts() function. That's the question I'm asking

Comment: Yes, that is because you either need to return it or define it as a global variable (would not recommend...). Edit you actually return it in the ```signIn``` function, you can use that